# Tor exited during startup on fresh install

Tags: configuration, windows, help, browsers

I have used the Tor browser for a long time with no problem, but I got a new laptop recently and every time I install and run Tor, I get the same error.

`Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start.`

I tried to reinstall multiple times, hibernation isn't a problem as I did a full reboot, ISP and network don't filter Tor because I used it before with no problem. My torrc file was empty after the install but that shouldn't be a problem.

System OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Home 64-bit

Processor: Intel Core i7-1260P

Graphics card: Intel Iris Xe Graphics

Memory and storage: 32 GB LPDDR5 and 1 TB SSD

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an old trick from MicroSux :) They are binding unnamed system services on well-known ports of Tor, I2P and other peer-to-peer software, I've noticed it like in 2011 and still it happens. Use another port for your Tor to listen to - and it will be just fine. Also attach a startup log and your torrc config **with bridges and keys and addresses removed** so it will be easier to pinpoint a problem if it's not this case